# SQL Bulk Copy with Excel to SQL Server but with data modifications

Tags: sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I am reading up on `SQLBulkCopy` and would like to use it to import thousands of rows from an Excel document to SQL Server.  I keep reading articles that do it directly without modifying the data. I need to do some modifications and validations on the data in the Excel document before doing the `SQLBulkCopy`.  Is it possible to do this?  I would assume from the overloads I can modify the data and create a large `DataTable`, and import that `DataTable` with `WriteToServer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a DataReader or DataSet that you can iterate over for validation/modification before importing.

This utility might help you - http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: So it looks like it is possible to do validation on the file before importing.

Comment: Yes, I have done this myself using my own DataSet provider, although this tool should help make it easier.  After validation, you can either use the same DataSet tables to perform the import, or you can use a separate SqlBulkCopy to work on the file directly.

Comment: Thanks.  There isn't a way to find out what row errored if the bulk insert fails is there?

Comment: I don't think the SQL error would include the row.  However, you can deduce it in one of 2 ways.  1) Wrap the bulk insert in a transaction, and if a failure occurs, check the target table before rolling back to see how many rows were successfully inserted (the error would be on the following row).  2) Set the NotifyAfter property to 1, and set the SqlRowsCopied callback to keep track of the rows processed.  If an error occurs, it will be on the row after the last one processed.  See this page for more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;

        //file upload path
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        //Create connection string to Excel work book
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
        //Create Connection to Excel work book
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        excelConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (dt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int t = 0;
        //excel data saves in temp file here.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            t++;
        }

        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, excelConnection);
        //excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
        //Give your Destination table name
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "[FSM].[DFS_Akustik]";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();

        ViewBag.view_dfs_akustik = dbman.View_DFS_Akustik.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```